# Как отправить запрос с параметрами на jsonbin .io?

Tags: javascript

Есть json - [ссылка](https://api.jsonbin.io/b/62828821019db46796a17fb2/)

Как получить, к примеру, первого пользователя?
Какой заголовок нужно отправить?
Делал как здесь - [твиттер](https://twitter.com/jsonbin/status/1413187630741688321)

но ничего не вышло.

Comment: получить "первого" пользователя можно через обращение к первому элементу [массива](https://learn.javascript.ru/array)

Comment: @Bald  Проблема в том, что нужного юзера необходимо сразу получать с сервера, а не со все данных, которые мы получили.

Comment: @Bald Пример их методички - [jsonbin](https://jsonbin.io/api-reference/bins/json-path#data-access-examples)

Comment: по идее надо указать заголовок для запроса `'X-JSON-Path': '$..users[*]..country'` и в ответ должен прийти массив городов, но почему то возвращается `{ users: []}`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let url = 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/62828821019db46796a17fb2/';

const fetchData = async () => {
  let fetchedData = await fetch(url)
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.users;
    });
    
    console.log(fetchedData);
    //Первый
    console.log(fetchedData[0]);
    //Второй
    console.log(fetchedData[1]);
}

fetchData();
```

Comment: Наверное, полностью не раскрыл свой вопрос. Проблема в том, что нужного юзера необходимо сразу получать с сервера, а не со все данных, которые мы получили.

Comment: Пример их методички - [jsonbin](https://jsonbin.io/api-reference/bins/json-path#data-access-examples)